# Como unir datos desde una columna segun palabra clave SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, tsql

es mi segunda pregunta aquí , tuve un problema en sql server , ya que hice un código en la versión 2017 y al querer pasarlo a una versión anterior me dio problemas la función STRING_AGG, que esta no era soportada por la versión , quería ver si esta la posibilidad de reemplazar esa función con otra que funcione de manera parecida.
Tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

parte del fragmento de la función es así:
`CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX('DOS:',STRING_AGG(LINEA, '')) > 0 THEN   SUBSTRING (STRING_AGG(LINEA, ''),CHARINDEX('PRIMERO UNO:',STRING_AGG(LINEA, '')),CHARINDEX('DOS:',STRING_AGG(LINEA, ''))-CHARINDEX('PRIMERO UNO:',STRING_AGG(LINEA, '')))`

Su objetivo era unir desde las palabras "PRIMERO UNO:" hasta la palabra "DOS:" en una sola linea, el resultado de la función seria.

PRIMERO UNO:- Por escritura pública otorgada con fecha11/07/2017, ante Notario Público de Santiago don(a) FELIX JARA, don(a)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Cédula de Identidad número xxxxxxxxx; constituyó prenda y prohibición especial a que se refiere a la ley20.190, a favor de la sociedad MITSUI AUTO FINANCE CHILE LIMITADA,inscribiéndose en el Registro de Prenda sin Desplazamiento bajo el repertorionúmero 189861-2017 y a la vez la anotación de prenda bajo el número 241339-2017, y la prohibición en el mismo Registro bajo el número 241340, ambas confecha 11/07/2017.- Los gravámenes recién referidos se constituyeron sobre elvehículo y sus accesorios, que se individualiza a continuación:- AUTOMOVIL,MARCA TOYOTA, MODELO COROLLA GL 1.8, MOTOR xxxxxxxx, CHASIS5YFBU8HE6HP666535, COLOR BLANCO, AÑO 2017, inscrito a su nombre en elregistro nacional de vehículos motorizados bajo el número xxxxxxx.

Mi pregunta es ¿existe una función que haga lo mismo que el STRING_AGG para obtener este mismo resultado pero que me sirva en una versión mas antigua de sql server?

Cualquier dato y ayuda se agradece!
pd:la imagen la raye para no dar datos personales de las personas

Comment: No, no existe función altenativa. Lo que se suele hacer es pasar por XML y usar `STUFF`. Te sugiero que reformules tu pregunta, enfocándola unicamente al  problema en sí. Saludos.

Comment: No tenia idea eso del XML Y STUFF gracias por guiarme!